# Pycharm intellisense not working

Tags: python, pycharm, python-3.4

Basically pycharm is underlining everything in red (even the os module) but everything runs fine.

How can I fix this ?

I am using the latest professional version(5.0.1) on a debian 8 with openjdk 1.7

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PyCharm` actually creates 2 virtualenvs-interpreters. One named `'ftv'` and one `'ftv(1)'`.

The second one worked even though on disk I only have 1 virtualenv, named `'ftv'`.